# Using async pipe with ngIf

Tags: angular

For the `status` property declared and populated like below:

```
  public status:Promise<String>;

  constructor() {
    this.status = this.getStatus();
  }

  public getStatus():Promise<String>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
          resolve('stable');
        },2500);
    });
   }
```

could somebody explain how the below `async` pipe works?

```
    <span *ngIf="status|async">
        {{ status|async }}
    </span>
```

Comment: The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. In your code async pipe will trigger when the promise `(this.status)` is completed with the value `stable`, Your promise is completed after 2.5sec (via SetTimeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to combine `*ngIf` and `async` like so:

My component will have an Observable (or in your case a Promise), with a variable name that ends with `$`. This naming pattern comes from [the observable naming guide here](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  //Create a subject with an initial value
  //Keep the subject private so only this component may emit value
  private _mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>('initial value!');

  //Expose the observable as a public variable
  //This allows the template to listen for values
  get myObservable$() {
    return this._mySubject.asObservable();
  }

  //helpers for demo!

  emitNull() {
    this._mySubject.next(null);
  }

  emitUndefined() {
    this._mySubject.next(undefined);
  }

  emitNumber(number) {
    this._mySubject.next(number);
  }

  emitText(text) {
    console.log(text);
    this._mySubject.next(text);
  }
}
```

Then my template:

```
<div>
  <button (click)="emitNull()">Emit Null</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="emitUndefined()">Emit Undefined</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="emitNumber(num.value)">Emit Number</button>
  <input type="number" #num value="42" />
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="emitText(txt.value)">Emit String</button>
  <input type="text" #txt value="foo" />
</div>

<br />

<h1>Value:</h1>
<ng-container *ngIf="myObservable$ | async as value; else other">
  <div>{{ value }}</div>
  ​ ​</ng-container
>

<ng-template #other>
  <div>The value was null, undefined or empty string</div>
</ng-template>
```

The template essentially reads as:

```
if(somevalue) 
    render a div displaying the value
else 
    render a div with text "The value was null..."
```

The key thing is that `async` is a `pipe`. A `pipe` always transforms some input. In this case, we're passing in an observable (or a promise) and getting some output.

So putting it all together, the template is:

1. Subscribing to the observable (or `then'ing` in the case of a promise),
2. Outputting a something whenever a new value is emitted, capturing it in a variable named `value`
3. Performing the `if` check on `value`
4. Conditionally rendering the stuff inside `ng-container` or using the template marked with `#other`

[Here's a stackblitz demonstrating the above!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjmfek?file=src/app/app.component.html)

As an aside, I recognize my example is using Observable instead of Promises. As I understand it, they essentially work the same. However, I strongly recommend using Observables over Promises in any Angular application. Observables are far more flexible and I think you'll run into far less confusing behavior.

Comment: How does `*ngIf` behave during the time when the promise is being resolved?

Comment: I updated my answer to go into a little more detail.

Comment: Thank you, things are clear now.